# jQuery :last or :lastChild and how?

Tags: jquery, class

Trying to remove the last child of an element only if the class = "dp_add_section", otherwise, I don't want to remove the last child.

How do I do this in jQuery?  Here's what I got so far, but it only removes the next element, can't wrap my head around trying to use the last selector for this...

```
if (pTd.next().attr('class') == 'dp_add_section')
    pTd.next().remove(".dp_add_section");
```

pTd is a variable that obtains the actual  element that I need for this.  So if I use `pTd.parent()` this gives me the `<tr>` element, but how do I remove the last `<td>` within here ONLY if the last `<td>` element has a `class="dp_add_section"`?

Thanks guys :)

Comment: Can you post your html. I am confused trying to figure out which elements have which classes.

Comment: Also, is there anyway to determine if the last `<td>` element has a class of `dp_add_section` or not?  I need to determine if the class exists also.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
pTd.parent().children('.dp_add_section:last-child').remove();
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure on the difference between them in speed or functionality, but I've decided to use this approach here instead of the others.

Comment: Other solution will not work because pTd.find('.dp_add_section:last-child') will not find anything. Use this it will work fine.

Comment: Question:  Is there anyway to determine if the `last-child` has a class of `class="dp_add_section"` and return true/false if it doesn't?  Basically I also need to know if the class exists in all `last-childs` of all `<tr>` elements, if so, I need to delete it from all `<tr>` elements as well.  But only if ALL `<tr>` elements have a `<td class="dp_add_section">content</td>` as the very last-child of the `<tr>` element.

Comment: @SoLoGHoST - I would post this in a new question. The specs are quite different from this question and it isn't very fair to create a moving target =)

Answer (score 3):

If I understood you correctly, you actually want something like this:

```
pTd.find('.dp_add_section:last-child').remove();
```

This removes the last-child **inside** `pTd` *if it has the class `dp_add_section`*.

Comment: `pTd.parent().find('.dp_add_section:last-child').remove();` works for me!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pTd.find('td.dp_add_section').last().remove();
```

or

```
pTd.find('td.dp_add_section:last').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can remove your last td by using the following code:

```
  $("table tr").each(function () {
      $(this).find('td.dp_add_section:last').remove();
  });
```

Used each loop to delete `<td>` with the mentioned class throughout the table.